# Error starting yugabyte as per shown in docs

Tags: node.js, database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

I ran yb-ctl create as specified at https://download.yugabyte.com/local#linux and ran into these errors

```
13:10 $ bin/yb-ctl create
Creating cluster.
Waiting for cluster to be ready.
Viewing file /net/dev-server-sanketh-3/share/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.err:
/tmp/pkg1/yugabyte-2.0.7.0/bin/yb-tserver: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Viewing file /net/dev-server-sanketh-3/share/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/master.err:
/tmp/pkg1/yugabyte-2.0.7.0/bin/yb-master: error while loading shared libraries: libatomic.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/yb-ctl", line 1968, in <module>
    control.run()
  File "bin/yb-ctl", line 1945, in run
    self.args.func()
  File "bin/yb-ctl", line 1707, in create_cmd_impl
    self.wait_for_cluster_or_raise()
  File "bin/yb-ctl", line 1552, in wait_for_cluster_or_raise
    raise RuntimeError("Timed out waiting for a YugaByte DB cluster!")
RuntimeError: Timed out waiting for a YugaByte DB cluster!
Viewing file /tmp/tmp3NIbj3:
2019-12-06 13:10:18,634 INFO: Starting master-1 with:
/tmp/pkg1/yugabyte-2.0.7.0/bin/yb-master --fs_data_dirs "/net/dev-server-sanketh-3/share/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1" --webserver_interface 127.0.0.1 --rpc_bind_addresses 127.0.0.1 --v 0 --version_file_json_path=/tmp/pkg1/yugabyte-2.0.7.0 --webserver_doc_root "/tmp/pkg1/yugabyte-2.0.7.0/www" --callhome_enabled=false --replication_factor=1 --yb_num_shards_per_tserver 2 --ysql_num_shards_per_tserver=2 --master_addresses 127.0.0.1:7100 --enable_ysql=true >"/net/dev-server-sanketh-3/share/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/master.out" 2>"/net/dev-server-sanketh-3/share/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/master.err" &
2019-12-06 13:10:18,658 INFO: Starting tserver-1 with:
/tmp/pkg1/yugabyte-2.0.7.0/bin/yb-tserver --fs_data_dirs "/net/dev-server-sanketh-3/share/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1" --webserver_interface 127.0.0.1 --rpc_bind_addresses 127.0.0.1 --v 0 --version_file_json_path=/tmp/pkg1/yugabyte-2.0.7.0 --webserver_doc_root "/tmp/pkg1/yugabyte-2.0.7.0/www" --callhome_enabled=false --tserver_master_addrs=127.0.0.1:7100 --yb_num_shards_per_tserver=2 --redis_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:6379 --cql_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:9042 --local_ip_for_outbound_sockets=127.0.0.1 --use_cassandra_authentication=false --ysql_num_shards_per_tserver=2 --enable_ysql=true --pgsql_proxy_bind_address=127.0.0.1:5433 >"/net/dev-server-sanketh-3/share/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.out" 2>"/net/dev-server-sanketh-3/share/yugabyte-data/node-1/disk-1/tserver.err" &
2019-12-06 13:10:18,662 INFO: Waiting for master and tserver processes to come up.
2019-12-06 13:10:29,126 INFO: PIDs found: {'tserver': [None], 'master': [None]}
2019-12-06 13:10:29,127 ERROR: Failed waiting for master and tserver processes to come up.
^^^ Encountered errors ^^^
```

Could you please let me know as to how I could fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `./bin/post_install.sh` from the setup ?

If yes, maybe you're missing `apt-get install libatomic1` ?